Bluetooth over-ear headphones where automatic standby/sleep/power saving can be disabled, for autistic person
I am looking for headphones for a person with autism. They like over ear headphones that can block outside noise (to prevent sensory over stimulation is some situations) and fit snugly and securely.
Usually they will wear the headphones and somebody else will play music from their phone or a dedicated MP3 jukebox via bluetooth.
The problem with the current headphones is that if the listener and the person carrying the device playing the music become separated for any period of time then the headphones will go into standby mode since there is no bluetooth signal between the device and headphones for a time and the only way to wake them from standby is to press a button on the headphones themselves.
Since the person with autism doesn't understand why the music has stopped, they don't know that they have to press the button on the headphones to turn it back on, they also aren't comfortable with somebody else pressing the button while they are wearing the headphones (and will get upset if someone tries), and they usually don't want to take the headphones off. This means that they have to do without the music as soon as this physical separation happens once.
What would be useful is a pair of headphones where this feature can disabled, so that if separation were the occur then the headphones will be able to simply reconnect to the playing device as soon as it is back in range. Obviously this means the battery might drain faster, but this is not such a big issue as long as the headphones have at least 2-3 hours of life since they can be charged later.
It would also be useful if the headphones can remember this setting so that even if they are connected to different devices, you don't need any settings app etc on each device and it can be set once.
It would also be good if the headphones are reasonably durable, since they may be dropped. Active noise cancelling might also be a useful feature.
Budget would be anything under around $250.

Hi AmusedFigure, welcome to Hardware Recs! Couple questions: 1. Where is the music that's being played coming from? Is it stored on the MP3 jukebox/phone, or is it streamed via Spotify/Apple Music/et al? 2. Would it be better if the headphones (or another device which remains on the user's person) is able to always play the music, that way the music doesn't stop playing if there's a physical separation? It could still be remotely controllable from the phone, but it'd prevent interruptions if there's a separation.

Usually it's just mp3 files from a collection of music that they like that are played on shuffle. It would be good if the MP3s could be stored directly on the headphones, I know there were devices like this made, but I can't find any in current production, at least not from any reputable brand. Typically we don't get them to carry things on their person, since they are very likely to lose/throw away or try to swallow them etc.

Unfortunately I couldn't find any over-ear noise-cancelling headphones with integrated MP3 players; Sony has the WS623 Walkmans and Ozlo makes the Sleepbuds, but both of those are in-ears that rely on passive noise isolation rather than active noise cancellation. Thus, the following recommendations address your original intended use case.
Both my recommendations are among the most popular noise-cancelling wireless headphones available on the market; as such, this won't be a comprehensive review or comparison of their performance, since there are many head to head comparisons out there. Ultimately it'll probably come down mostly to personal preference, which may be hard to judge for your particular users.
Bose QuietComfort 45 (or similar) - $200ish

Most modern Bose noise cancelling headphones support disabling "Auto-off" via the Bose Music app; by default the QC 45s are set to never power off automatically. This setting is stored on-device, so you only need to set it once in the app.
The QC 45s are good all-rounders, with solid sound quality and excellent noise cancelling (with a variety of color options.) MSRP is $349, but they regularly go on sale for about $200 and are perpetually available on eBay for about that price, including from the official Bose store. The older QC 35 IIs would also work just fine, though they lack USB-C and some other nice-to-haves.
Sony WH-1000XM5/XM4 (or similar) - $200ish

Again, most modern Sony wireless noise cancelling headphones support configuration of the Automatic Power Off feature via the app. Unlike the QC 45s, the default behavior is to auto-power-off after 5 of 15 minutes (depending on the model), or when removed from the head, but this is fully configurable. These settings are stored on-device, so you only need to set it once in the app.
Like the QC 45s, the WH1000-XM5s/XM4s are good all-rounders, with solid sound quality and excellent noise cancelling (with a variety of color options.) MSRP is $399, but they regularly go on sale for about $300 and are perpetually available on eBay for about $200. The older XM4 and XM3 models would also work just fine; they have slightly fewer nice to haves, and a different appearance, but both have USB-C charging.
